# How to remove weird messages in Flutter

Tags: flutter

every time I run flutter I got these weird log messages but don't know how to remove it.
I'm using Samsung J7 Prime. Any help for removing these log messages?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eT2Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was asked some time ago in a Flutter Slack group I am part of, and the consensus was that there's no way to turn off these log messages.